# Can't move controls on form after upgrading from VS2010 to VS2013

Tags: forms, visual-studio-2013

using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013 Version 12.0.30324.0 REL Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.5.50938

I just upgraded a project from VS2010 to VS2013.  On certain forms I can no longer use the mouse to move or resize controls.  In some cases when attempting this VS2013 locks up

It's not just the controls either. I can't use the mouse to resize a "sizable" form. I also can't drop new controls on the form. I can however use shift arrow keys to resize the form and key in the size I want under properties. No I'm not debugging. Yes I have my snap to grid settings the way I want them. No I don't have controls "locked". This is clearly a phenomenon with VS2013. Occasionally, by futsing around with it the form seems to fix itself and the mouse actions function as normal. But as soon as I exit VS2013 and restart it, the ability to use the mouse on a form in design mode is hosed again. The issue seems worse on forms with many controls but can occur on any form.

As an experiment I created a new plain Jane form in VS2013 and dropped a couple buttons on it. I was able to resize the form with the mouse and do whatever I needed. However, when I exited VS and restarted it, The form exhibited the same behavior as my converted forms, in that I could no longer resize it or move my controls around.

I believe the issue is with the IDE and I'm forced to roll back to VS2010 so I can actually continue development.

I do also have VS2010 installed on the same PC which is suppose to be fine and dandy so I'm wondering it there is in fact some sort of conflict occurring.

If someone has some new insight on this I would love for you to share.

Thanks and happy coding,

Chris

Comment: Still got both versions on the machine? My first suspicion would be that something around the install had stuffed up badly (not the first time ever with ms products :( ... ). So it would be uninstall and install or (insert chose deity here) forfend, nuke the machine and start again. Another thing to look at is are you fully patched / updated. Given you have problems with vanilla vs2013 projects, its nothing to do with converting at least.

Comment: (What's with this 5 minute editor thing in SO?)

Hi Tony, thanks for your reply.

I actually tried to uninstall VS2013 with the intention of reinstalling it and it failed with some error message that stated in so many words that it encountered an unknown error.  Bottom line I can not uninstall it from my machine.  So given this I'm inclined to agree with you that something ginipped when it should have ginopped during the install

Nuking my machine and starting again is typically a three day ordeal, one that I don't relish doing. 

Thanks again for your post.

Chris

Comment: You could try something like RevoUninstaller on it, but as we know installing VS is installing heck of a lot of other stuff...